# Specflow 2.3.2: why is Specflow generating *.cs files using "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools" instead of "NUnit.Framework"

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

**Question**: why is Specflow using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute() to generate the *.cs code behind for the feature files instead of the NUnit.Framework? Both solutions described below use the same NuGet packages from what I can see.

---

**Details**:

I have one project that generates the Specflow codebehind *.cs files and only uses NUnit. 
[image: Specflow codebehind using all NUnit]

There is a second project (in a separate solution) which always uses "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute()" instead of using the NUnit Fromework. 
[image: Specflow codebehind which always wants to use MS testtools unit testing]

I did a search in the second solution for the words "VisualStudio.TestTools" and the only place it showed up was in the TechTalk.SpecFlow.Reporting.dll.

**Question**: why is Specflow using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute() to generate the *.cs code behind for the feature files instead of the NUnit.Framework? Both solutions use the same NuGet packages from what I can see.

Comment: Have you added the [`SpecFlow.NUnit`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.NUnit) package?

Comment: @DavidG Thanks. that gave me some other error messages that I am more familiar with. I'm going to try to update Specflow to 3.0 and get rid of the SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator Custom Tool and see where that gets me. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Specflow 2.3.2 you need to have this "unitTestProvider" in your App.config.  But yeah you should probably just upgrade to 3.0

```
<specFlow>
<plugins>
  <add name="SpecRun" />
  <!--<add name="SpecFlow.Retry" path="..\packages\SpecFlow.Retry.2.4.0\lib\net45" type="Generator" />-->
</plugins>

<!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
<!-- use unit test provider SpecRun+NUnit or SpecRun+MsTest for being able to execute the tests with SpecRun and another provider -->
<unitTestProvider name="SpecRun+NUnit" />
</specFlow>
```

Comment: I upgraded to Specflow 3.0 and everything builds as expected. Thanks.